# Could not load file or assembly 'Common.Logging, Version=3.0.0.0'

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net, common.logging

I'm trying to use log4net in my project, so i configured the log4net, created an appender and created the ILog object, and even tried to write to the eventviewer and it worked, here is the definition of the ILog.
But when I'm Trying to pass the log into another class, I get this exception :

> Could not load file or assembly 'Common.Logging, Version=3.0.0.0. Culture=neutral...

```
private readonly ILog _log;

public Class()
{
    XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    _log = LogManager.GetLogger(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);
    // This works.
    _log.Error("Test");

    triggerListener = new TriggerListener(_log);
}
```

Comment: Is the assembly present on disk?

Comment: all i have is the dll of log4net

Answer (score 3):

You need to check if the file `Common.Logging.dll` is in the bin directory of your project.

If it is not there copy the file there. If it is there check the version of the `.dll`. It is probably not `3.0.0.0`.

Comment: I dont have this dll, is this dll a part of log4net?

Comment: No it is not part of log4net, common.logging is a logging framework on top of other logging frameworks. There has to be some reference somewhere in your project.

Comment: Well, I dont have it, and i cant seem to find it, i also use Quartz and i think it uses the Common.Logging, but how come it doesnt find it?